# php reload with all data

Tags: php

I need to reload the page with all the post data that gets sent to it, the post data is a array also which might make it a bit harder.

So this is the code that I use to reload the page. (this is the exact same page, so reloading the page)

```
//there is no data so lets do something as the ajax call is waiting for data
        header('Location: checkchat.php, true, 302);
        exit;
```

I need it to submit the array to the the same page, through ether `POST`, or `GET` and also, I **cant** print, any data out or my ajax request will return the data (which will be anything that the gets printed on the page).

The Array can have 200 values in it so I cant send it through `GET` well i could but it will unreasonable.

So the array is something like so...

array name = **Friendslist**

- fredy@example.com
- bob@example.com
- jimmy@example.com
- test@example.com

Comment: Is this data from an HTML form?

Comment: Are you attempting to build some sort of long-polling mechanism?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes using ajax and it will compare some values and if it is any different then print out the data and then the js will work in the data

Comment: I still don;t fully understand the use case as to why the server needs to redirect. Why wouldn't the client just make a new AJAX request every X seconds(or milliseconds)?

Comment: im using AJAX but it's not using async data, so it waits for the server to find changes and then prints the data out for the ajax to return the data to the javascript

Comment: I think i got it sorted, ill put up my answer if It works :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it took longer that I thought, but did it. I just added it into a session that gets over written every time, and I pull the array out of this.  Also It just refreshes the page like usual using...

```
 header('Location: checkchat.php, true, 302);
        exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to `POST` the data? Why can't you store it server side and then redirect as normal?

Comment: the data is saved in a server but. I want to work out the differences between two arrays it works fine, but I need to just refresh the page with exactly the same data, that gets sent to it

Comment: also this same request could be happening 100 times with over 3000 people, so the database could be flooded with data, its kind of an reasonable